# What is this Android drawable background resource?

Tags: java, android

I have just started learning Android, currently going through the tutorials on the Google Android developer website, so far not that impressed as there are a lot of things that go unexplained.

On the tutorial "Styling the Action Bar", it has the following XML style resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

(Android 2.1+ support)

At no point does it mention what the @drawable/actionbar_background is meant to be? As it is @drawable is this an image? I wouldn't understand why it would be as it's meant to be colouring the action bar background.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
<item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
```

translates to English like

> Add to this style an item representing a property called "background".
>   As the value of this property, set a resource of type "drawable" with
>   name "actionbar_background".

In this case the script will look for an image in the resources folder "drawable" the name of which matches the given one. If the line was

```
<item name="text">@string/actionbar_title</item>
```

The script would look in res/values for a resource defined as `<string>` with "name" property "actionbar_title".

Comment: So would that actionbar_background image just be an image of block colour?

Comment: It depends what is in the file :-) Android has several sets of resources, but the two most important are the ones you put in your app and system resources. In the above example the value references a system resource, so if you want to find what it is, pull this system revision from the repository and look for a file `actionbar_background` in the `res/drawable-xxxx` directories.

Comment: As a side note, a `drawable` type resource does not have to be an image. It may also be an XML in which an image is referenced or an XML which uses only colors. This lets us create more complex backgrounds and behaviors without writing a line of actual code.

Answer (score 0):

In the layout files for Android, the '@' symbol followed by a word like 'drawable' or 'style', refers to a path and file in the res or resource folder.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

`<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>` sets your actionBar's background to drawable(image) resource which is located in your project -> drawable folders.

I guess you can also use color to set your background like this:
`<item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>`